# How to set callback function at runtime in jQuery

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, jquery-callback

Is there any way of defining call back function at run time.
Here is what I need.
I am using fancybox.

```
$.fancybox.open({
            href : '#modal_div',
            minWidth:1150,
            minHeight:820,
            width:1150,
            height:820,
            autoResize:true,
            afterShow:function(){
                set_buttons();

            }
        });
```

In another part of script, If the value received from server side is "true" then fancybox closes. What I what is to define a callback "afterClose" so as to do some specific thing only when server response is true otherwise not and it should simply close.

```
$.post("user_action.php", {
                    delete_item:item_id,
                    rel:item_type
                }, function(data){
                            if(data=="true"){
                                $.fancybox.close()
                              //do some stuff afterClose
                            }
                            else{
                            $.fancybox.close()
                            }
                }
            });
```

so all I need is way to set callback function on the go!!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that I didn't correctly understand your question. If that is the case, please amend your OP and I'll try again.

You are actually in a call-back function already, and you have correctly structured your IF test to see if the value of "data" is true or not.

Therefore, you can do the desired stuff right where you put that comment -- immediately after the `$.fancybox.close();` instruction.

Note: Don't forget that you need a semi-colon after that instruction, right?